# Elastic search plugin

Tags: elasticsearch

I have used the command `bin/plugin --url file:///PATH-TO-EXAMPLE-PLUGIN/target/releases/example-plugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip --install example-plugin` to install my plugin, and get the jar in the subdirectory in the `/plugins`.

But when I use `bin/elasticsearch` to start the elastic search, get the follow message which looks like no plugin was loaded.

`[plugins] [Marduk Kurios] loaded [], sites []`

I want to know what's the possible matter, my plugin was written according to this  [tutorial](https://www.found.no/foundation/writing-a-plugin/).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the reason, which I get the file name of `es-plugin.properties` to `es-plugin.xxx` by mistake.